# How to update code OTA on ESP8266 keeping configuration

Tags: arduino, esp8266, ota

I have 3 homemade devices based on ESP8266. Each of them is intended for a different application, and all of them are really only for hobby.

Sometimes I just want to make a small change to the code, or add a new functionality, so I've been working on OTA updates over web.

Each board has the same code, but each has a unique ID defined on the code and some unique configuration they can access from a database on the web. Ideally, I could update the code in board #01, that board would search on a database table for the previous configuration on startup and everything would work well.

Problem is, when the code is changed, the ID (which is defined on the code) is lost, and i don't want to compile manually 3 different binaries, one for each board, with the ID as the only difference between them. Of course I have to do it on the first time I program this board, but I don't want to do it for every update.

Is there any way to update the code OTA but keep the ID on the board? Maybe a way to write this ID (or even other flags) in a non-replaced section of the memory.

Comment: What framework or development environment are you working in? Arduino? MicroPython? Lua? FreeRTOS? Something else?

Comment: I'm working with Arduino environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [ESP8266 has flash memory](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html), which persists even without power. This is where the firmware for the ESP8266 is stored.

You can use the [EEPROM library](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html) to store small amounts of data (between 4 and 4096 bytes) in the flash. The ESP8266 doesn't have a true EEPROM - the name of this library is a holdover from true Arduinos. On the ESP8266 it justs uses a small part of the flash and pretends it's an EEPROM.

If you use the EEPROM library, make sure you call `EEPROM.commit()` or `EEPROM.end()` after you write your data to make sure it's actually stored in the flash. This is different from the way it's used on Arduinos, and Arduino examples will usually not do this.

You can also use the [SPIFFS library](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html#file-system-object-spiffs) to store files in the flash - you might just store all the configuration information in a file (or the EEPROM space) rather than keeping it in your database.

Comment: It seems a lot like what I need. I'll see how it works for me, then come back here and say the results.

Comment: Worked fine, it was exactly what I was needing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution is nice and tested. The only thing that you have to concern is that the EEPROM has no infinite rewrites. I am keeping a signature that the first time does not exists so I write to EEPROM, and all other times only read the device ID because sigmature exists. Another solution is to read the specific byte from EEPROM before write and ignore if is equal.

Answer (score 0):

why You not uses the WiFi mac address as unique ID ?

So You can update some code in any boards, and this not lost the ID.

Comment: I might want to update the board from a place outside my LAN network

Comment: The MAC address is a hardware address which is permanent. It won't change when you're on a different network. The IP address will.

Comment: I remember setting the MAC address right on the code, and I put something random. Should I find out the real MAC address from the hardware and use it then?

Comment: Unless you have a very specific reason to change your board's MAC address (not IP address),  you should almost certainly let the board use its hardware MAC address and not change that.

Comment: I did remove the new MAC address statement from the code. I brought it from the example sketches and did not question. Thanks.

Comment: MAC address is not a good idea in case you replace the device. The best is to keep an ID at the EEPROM

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should've used the NodeMCU firmware...  You could just update your Lua scripts OTA and update your modules without even rebooting!